# WordPress Blocks / FSE / wp:query documentation

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am looking for the block markup / FSE documentation, for example in the twentytwentyfour theme archive.html template, there is this code :

```
wp:query-title {"type":"archive","align":"wide","style":{"typography":{"lineHeight":"1"},"spacing":{"padding":{"top":"var:preset|spacing|50"}}}}
```

Where can I find the documentation of available options for wp:query- ?
Basically like the [WP_Query PHP documentation page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/), but for blocks / FSE markup ?
For exemple, I would like to display a taxonomy description in the archive, how can I achieve this ?

Do I need to create a PHP pattern containing the term_description() php function and then call it from the html template with wp:template-part ? Or is there a a thing like wp:query-term-description ?

I have been going through the documentation but could not find anything, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there a a thing like wp:query-term-description ?

Indeed, to display the taxonomy description, you would add the term description block: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/term-description-block/

```
<!-- wp:term-description /-->
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not really answer my question. This is not a documentation page for developers... I think something is lacking here from WordPress.

Comment: I tried my best to understand what exactly you were asking, because you mention both wp:query, the query title, and how to display the description, but these are all separate things.

WordPress documentation, including the block editor handbook, does not include descriptions of the markup of each block. Nor what settings each block has. I agree that makes it more difficult for us as developers.

I built my own tool and reference, that parses the block.json file of the core blocks, and use the test fixtures to output the markup.
But I don't think I would be allowed to share the link here.

Comment: I believe the general consensus within the WordPress community, is that to get the block markup of each block, we should add it to the editor and copy it.
I am not saying that is ideal, but I believe that is how most of us are managing.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I had already check your website and it helped me, but what I would want is a documentation with all available "wp:"  blocks and how to use them in FSE websites. Anyway for now I got back to using Roots Sage and ACF for managing blocks...